# I am unable to save an image in database through java.I am getting this problems.Iam using netbeans and mysql to do this application

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, jdbc

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Practice.Photo.saveActionPerformed(Photo.java:161)
at Practice.Photo.access$200(Photo.java:20)
at Practice.Photo$3.actionPerformed(Photo.java:68)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 12 seconds)

here is my code that performing this task

Connecting to database

```
 private void connectActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    try {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/forjava","root", "Jilani");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Connected successfully...!");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Photo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Photo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Photo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Photo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Connection failed...!");
    }


    }
```

getting image file from the user

```
private void chooseActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
            // TODO add your handling code here:
    filechooser = new JFileChooser();
    filechooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
    String[] extensions = ImageIO.getReaderFileSuffixes();
    filechooser.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Image files",extensions));
    int status = filechooser.showOpenDialog(this);
            filechooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);
            if(status == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File file = filechooser.getSelectedFile();
        name=file.getPath();
        path.setText(name);
        try {
            File img=new File(name);
        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(img);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bao=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buf=new byte[1024];
        for(int rdnum;(rdnum=fis.read(buf))!=-1;) {
            bao.write(buf, 0, rdnum);
        }
        image=bao.toByteArray();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Photo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Photo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    }
```

and finally saving

```
  private void saveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
            // TODO add your handling code here:
    String sql="INSERT INTO photo(image) VALUES(?)";
    try {
        stmt.setBytes(1, image);
        stmt=con.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.executeUpdate();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Saved Successfully into Database...!");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Photo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }                   
    }
```

first the user will click on connect to databae then a popup shown connected successfully then after user select the image by using choose button then click on save to database it will be stored into data base but it is not happening it showing me an error .please help me to solve this problem i searched in google alot but i didnt solve it.

Comment: Something in line 161 of your class Photo is null what's not supposed to be null. What is in line 161?

Comment: this is in line 161 which is trying to store image      "stmt.setBytes(1, image);"

Comment: make sure you ONLY modify gui elements from the EventQueue using a invokeLater(new Runnable() { });, otherwise you will get weird exceptions that eventually boil down to access controls and threads. Also, your logging is hideous! logging needs to be simple! LOG.severe("Message", exception); is all it should take! Fix your logger!

Comment: And where do you initialize stmt? At least not somewhere in the code you showed us.

Comment: Paste your `Photo.java`

Comment: your `image` is `null` at statement `stmt.setBytes(1, image);` check

Comment: @Deepak, no, `stmt` is null.  He initializes it the line *after* he tries to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void saveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    String sql="INSERT INTO photo(image) VALUES(?)";
    try {
        stmt.setBytes(1, image);
        stmt=con.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.executeUpdate();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Saved Successfully into Database...!");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Photo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }                   
}
```

You're trying to call `stmt.setBytes(1, image)` before you've prepared the statement, so `stmt` is `null`.  This needs to be

```
private void saveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    String sql="INSERT INTO photo(image) VALUES(?)";
    try {
        stmt=con.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.setBytes(1, image);
        stmt.executeUpdate();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Saved Successfully into Database...!");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Photo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }                   
}
```